# StreamWriter inside Dispose

Tags: c#, dispose

I have the following code:

```
        public void Dispose()
        {
            bool append = true;
            using(var log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("log.txt", append))
            {
                log.WriteLine("Disposing");
                log.Flush();
            }
        }
```

So there's the risk that the StreamWriter may throw an exception, would that then mean that my object would not get disposed? Would simply wrapping this in a Try/Catch solve the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not confident enough with this answer to post in the answers box, but I believe that your object will get disposed anyway as any managed object would, just that the rest of your dispose method won't run.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Dispose/IDisposable is used for releasing unmanaged resources which are missing in the Dispose method. Only logging is done

Comment: It's just an example of a case where an error could occur inside the Dispose, and this is how the question was put to me in an interview, so hence how I posted it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by this:

> would that then mean that my object would not get disposed?

Your object has had `Dispose` called on it, otherwise it wouldn't have reached the `StreamWriter` code. That `Dispose` call may not have completed, but it's not like there's some magical flag on an object saying "disposed or not disposed".

Note that disposal is logically separate from garbage collection and finalization: your object *will* still become eligible for garbage collection in the same way as normal (when there are no live references) and if you have a finalizer (almost certainly not a good idea) it will still be called if you haven't suppressed it.

It's important to understand that although C# has support for `IDisposable` at the language level, the CLR *really* doesn't care about it. It's just another interface, and `Dispose` is just another method.

In general it's a bad idea for `Dispose` to throw an exception (as if an object is disposed as part of cleaning up an existing failing operation, you end up losing the original exception) but it's not going to fundamentally damage the CLR in some way.

Answer (score 0):

> So there's the risk that the StreamWriter may throw an exception, would that then mean that my object would not get disposed? Would simply wrapping this in a Try/Catch solve the issue?

If StreamWriter will throw exception, only side effect will be that following will not execute.

```
 log.WriteLine("Disposing");
 log.Flush();
```

Rest everything will be as expected.
StreamWriter will be disposed properly as well. (That is the purpose of `using` keyword)

Comment: Well the `StreamWriter` won't be disposed if the *constructor* throws an exception - the calling code would have nothing to dispose. But hopefully in that case it would already have cleared up any resources it had got as far as allocating.

Comment: i am aware, but as you have mentioned, there is nothing to dispose then. I should have been explicit though.