# Member variable access in Dispose

Tags: c#, dispose

I'm trying to learn more about the Dispose method and how things happening in this might stall the Garbage collection of this object.

So, if I have:

```
DateTime _date = DateTime.UtcNow;

public void Dispose()
{
   bool append = true;
   using(var log = new System.IO.StreamWriter("log.txt", append))
   {
       log.WriteLine("Logged on: " + _date);
   }
}
```

Will the fact that I'm calling the _date in the Dispose method re-root the variable and not allow the GC to collect this?

This is leading on from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248937/streamwriter-inside-dispose).

Comment: 1. Dispose has nothing to do with GC. 2. Dispose should never throw an exception, but your code could easily thrown exceptions.

Comment: Right, these are two things I got from the linked post which Jon mentioned. So is this the only real issue with the code above? That it might throw an exception, however it would still be collected correctly?

Comment: @Richard - It will _not_ throw and everything will be collected.

Comment: @Henk - Could it not throw due to an issue with writing the file (disk full or the like)?

Comment: Yes, that part might throw. But then indeed GC and Dispose are unrelated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The garbage collector has **nothing whatsoever** to do with `Dispose()`, so the simple answer is: not at all. GC involves the finalizer (`~YourType()`), but *not* `Dispose()`, unless you mean the common `Dispose(bool disposing) {...}` pattern.

Secondly, a `DateTime` is a `struct`, and is thus not garbage collected.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not. Dispose has essentially nothing to do with garbage collection (aside from the fact that many implementations will call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)`.)

The dispose pattern allows consumers of an object to be polite, and release unmanaged resources as soon as possible. Garbage collection is the standard method for releasing managed resources when appropriate.

Some disposable classes will *also* implement a finalizer so that if the object is collected without being disposed, an emergency freeing of the unmanaged resources can occur.